# Is it possible to export base colors as images?

Tags: objects, export

I'm not really sure how to say it, but basically, I have a simple rocket model made from few cylinders and cones.
I gave each of them a base color and now, if possible, I would like to somehow combine those colors into one texture for the whole model, and export the image. (I need the image as a separate png as that's the only way the texture will show up in the program where it's being exported)

I have no knowledge of blender at all, so I'm sorry if I'm doing it all wrong.

Comment: yes you can bake multiple materials into one, you'll easily find some YT tutorials

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 methods:

Duplicate your object, remove the materials of the copy, unwrap it with the *Smart UV Project* mode, give it a new material with an *Image Texture* node plugged into a *Diffuse* or *Emission* or *Principled BSDF*. Create a new image in the *Image Texture*. Select the original object, shift select the new one, make sure that you are in Cycles, go into the *Render panel > Bake* > choose *Bake Type > Diffuse*, deactivate *Direct* and *Indirect* lights, activate *Selected to Active*, increase the *Extrusion* value a bit, then click on the *Bake* button, now you should have the colors of the first object printed on the image.

Other method:

Create an *Image Texture* node, give it a new image, copy paste this node in each of the materials of your object, don't plug it, keep it selected if you have other *Image Texture* nodes in these materials, in *Edit* mode unwrap your object (choose *Smart UV Project* mode, if you already used UV maps in your materials, create a new one in the *Object Data panel > UV Map*, unwrap and plug a *UV Map node* into the new *Image Texture* with this new UV map loaded):

[image]

Now make sure that you are in Cycles, go in the *Render panel > Bake*, choose *Bake Type > Diffuse*, deactivate *Direct* and *Indirect* lights, then click on the *Bake* button:

[image]

Now you have a *Diffuse* UV map, give your object a new and unique material, plug the *Image Texture* into the *Principled BSDF* (or *Diffuse*, or *Emission*):

[image]